# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Acme\RegisterUser' not found

Tags: php, oop

I'm learning all about namespaces in PHP but I haven't got a clue what I am doing wrong?

Here is my directory structure:

```
/review
├── index.php
├── RegisterUser.php
└── AuthController.php
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
$registration = new Acme\RegisterUser;

$authController = new Acme\AuthController($registration);

$authController->register();
```

**RegisterUser.php**

```
<?php namespace Acme;

class RegisterUser
{
    public function execute(array $data, $listener)
    {
        var_dump('registering the user');

        $listener->userRegisteredSuccessfully();
    }
}
```

and **AuthController.php**

```
<?php namespace Acme;

    class AuthController {

        protected $registration;

        public function __construct(RegisterUser $registration, $listener) {
            $this->registration = $registration;
        }

        public function register() {
            $this->registration->execute([], $this);
        }

        public function userRegisteredSuccessfully() {
            var_dump('created successsfully. redirect somewhere');
        }

        public function userRegisteredFailed() {
            var_dump('created unsuccessfully. redirect back');
        }

    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using PHP version `PHP 7.1.0RC6 (cli) (built: Nov  9 2016 04:45:59) ( NTS )`

Error:

```
> $ php index.php                                                                                      [±master ●]
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Acme\RegisterUser' not found in /Users/dan/Desktop/oop/src/review/index.php:2
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /Users/dan/Desktop/oop/src/review/index.php on line 2

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Acme\RegisterUser' not found in /Users/dan/Desktop/oop/src/review/index.php:2
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /Users/dan/Desktop/oop/src/review/index.php on line 2
```

Comment: What happens if you put a slash before the fully qualified class name (Eg: new \Acme\RegisterUser)?

Comment: How are you including the files that contain the classes? Manually? Autoloader?

Comment: You need to load the appropriate classes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: You may want to think about mirroring your namespaces in folder form and auto loading. You will save yourself a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include those classes first, either by autoloading or manually.

Comment: That's what I figured but the reason I asked was because I Was following along Laracasts and they did not have that line in so I wondered how he was doingi t. Thank you.

Comment: How would you do this, with the same code examples?